# Using @Lock annotation instead of the synchronized keyword

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, concurrency, singleton, session-bean

### Application Setup (simplified)

I feel like I am pretty familiar with concurrency in Java, but I am relatively new to Java EE and its annotations.

I have a class called `DataHandler` annotated with `@Singleton` that performs some business logic for my application. This class is injected into a web service implementation class annotated with `@WebService`. When one of the web service's methods is called, `DataHandler` calls the `parseFiles()` method which parses some files, and stores data inside of `DataHandler`. Afterwards it makes some calls to getters inside of `DataHandler`:

```
@WebService(portName = "portName",
    serviceName = "MyService",
    endpointInterface = "com.myco.MyPortType",
    wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/MyWSDL.wsdl",
    targetNamespace = "targetNamespace")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyPortType {

@EJB
private DataHandler dataHandler;

@Override
public ResponseType doStuff(RequestType request) {
    // code
    // ....
    dataHandler.parseFiles();
    // ....
    // more code
    Map<String, CustomType> map = dataHandler.getCustomTypeMap();
    Map<String, CustomType2> map2 = dataHandler.getCustomType2Map();
}
```

Now I also have message-driven bean that receives some data on a topic called UpdateTopic, then converts it into another type and stores it inside of `DataHandler`:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "UpdateTopic")
})
public class UpdateTopicMDB implements MessageListener {

@EJB
DataHandler dataHandler;

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
            ObjectMessage objMessage = (ObjectMessage) message;
            Serializable data = objMessage.getObject();
            if (data instanceof UpdateType) {
                dataHandler.convertAndStore((UpdateType) data);
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // log Exception
    }
}
```

I wanted to synchronize the `parseFiles()` method, the `convertAndStore()` method, and the two getters so that all data would be up-to-date when accessed.

I simply made all four methods `synchronized` to achieve this. My understanding is that if the files were in the middle of being parsed and an update comes into the MDB, then the `convertAndStore()` method would be locked until `parseFiles()` is done. Likewise, if an update is being converted and stored and the web service is trying to access one of the two maps, it will wait until `convertAndStore()` is finished. Correct me if I'm wrong on any of that.

---

### My Question

With all of that being said, I just recently read about the `@ConcurrencyManagement` and `@Lock` annotations. Instead of synchronizing these four methods. It now seems as though I should just annotate `parseFiles()` and `convertAndStore()` with `@Lock(LockType.WRITE)` since they are modifying the bean's state and the two getters with `@Lock(LockType.READ)`.

Should I do this and avoid using the `synchronized` keyword altogether? Would there be any use for `synchronized` (maybe just for synchronized blocks?), or do these annotations replace it now?

Answer (score 0):

When you code JavaEE, you should avoid `synchronized` and any other manual concurrency implementation. Do not create threads and locks. Instead of that use [JSR 236 (EE concurrency utilities)](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/EE+Concurrency+Utilities?_sscc=t).

Comment: Thanks for the first point about not using `synchronized`, but I don't really think my application needs to set up a thread factory or executor service. I simply need to synchronize access to these methods and was wondering if replacing `synchronized` with these `@Lock` annotations would do what I thought it would do.

Comment: Read [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Lock.html), it says: "Declares a concurrency lock for a **singleton session bean** with container managed concurrency. // If this annotation is _not used_, a _value of Lock(WRITE) is assumed_." So, you dont need to specify `WRITE` Lock type explicitely, but if you want lock on read, use `@Lock(LockType.READ)`.

Comment: Ah okay, so it seems as though my application was pretty much fine before I even tried using the `synchronized` keyword since container-managed concurrency is used by default on singletons. Should I bother adding `@Lock(LockType.READ)` on my getters? Or will it really make a difference?

Comment: Yes, add lock on read for every mthod which has to be locked on read.